# C++ Lua ThreadSafe

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua

I have some problems with `c++` & `lua` threading.
My project is loading `.lua` files to single `Lua_State` (need for their synergy). Also, it adds some LuaRefs to vector to use it later in callbacks.
The only problem I currently have is `no TheadSafe`. I've tried to create `mutex` objects and lock them before calling each of vector -> then unlocking...

For Example:

```
std::vector<luabridge::LuaRef> drawCall;
void OnDraw()
{
    try { for (luabridge::LuaRef f : drawCall) f(); } 
    catch (luabridge::LuaException ex) { Msg(ex.what()); }
}
void AddDrawCall(luabridge::LuaRef obj) { if (!obj.isNil()) drawCall.push_back(obj); }
```

Where `AddDrawCall` is called from lua and adding function to `drawCall` as LuaRef.
`OnDraw()` is called from another thread using `detoured` function.
With global mutex I have huge performance drop -> Blinking drawings, etc.
Btw I have seen that there are other solutions: Calling `lua_newthread` or creating several `Lua_State`s but have no idea how to do it with this callbacks :(

Comment: lua is inherently not thread safe, you should not use a single lua state from multiple threads. each lua_State * has some data associated to what it is currently doing, where the stack is, etc., you will get havoc if two threads are clobbering that stuff. Can you use a different `lua_State *` for each thread?

Comment: Currently I can't do it (I think so). I need synergy between thread's callbacks which are LuaRefs. Have no idea if Lua_States could reflect each other.